# In R, date type column shows no timestamp, but as.numeric does. What's going on?

Tags: r, date, datetime

I've got a date column in R, which I've queried from an SQLite database, like so. SQLite dates are stored as numbers, much like Excel.

```r
# SQLite date origin, like POSIX, is 1970-01-01
> dat$sample_date_time <- as.Date(dat$sample_date_time, origin = "1970-01-01")

> str(dat$sample_date_time)
Date[1:21312], format: "2021-10-12" "2021-10-12" "2021-10-12" "2021-10-12" ...
```

Everything looks good. However, I've been running into an issue where when I try to subset the data by a unique date, the "ghosts of timestamps past" are haunting me.

```r
# This is returning 19 dates, not 1 unique date!
> format(unique(dat$sample_date_time), '%d %B, %Y %H %M %s')
 [1] "24 November, 2021 00 00 1637730000"
 [2] "24 November, 2021 00 00 1637730000"
 [3] "24 November, 2021 00 00 1637730000"
 [4] "24 November, 2021 00 00 1637730000"
 [5] "24 November, 2021 00 00 1637730000"
 [6] "24 November, 2021 00 00 1637730000"
 [7] "24 November, 2021 00 00 1637730000"
 [8] "24 November, 2021 00 00 1637730000"
 [9] "24 November, 2021 00 00 1637730000"
[10] "24 November, 2021 00 00 1637730000"
[11] "24 November, 2021 00 00 1637730000"
[12] "24 November, 2021 00 00 1637730000"
[13] "24 November, 2021 00 00 1637730000"
[14] "24 November, 2021 00 00 1637730000"
[15] "24 November, 2021 00 00 1637730000"
[16] "24 November, 2021 00 00 1637730000"
[17] "24 November, 2021 00 00 1637730000"
[18] "24 November, 2021 00 00 1637730000"
[19] "24 November, 2021 00 00 1637730000"
```

When I query/susbet it as numeric, I see that the dates are not unique!

```r
> as.numeric(dat$sample_date_time)
 [1] 18955.45 18955.45 18955.46 18955.47 18955.48 18955.48
 [7] 18955.49 18955.49 18955.45 18955.46 18955.47 18955.47
[13] 18955.48 18955.49 18955.49 18955.50 18955.50 18955.50
[19] 18955.50
```

My quick and dirty way of dealing with this is to just use `floor` on the numeric date and then convert back to date. Is there a better way to do this? Is there a way to just subset by date, ignoring the timestamp, without resorting to `as.numeric() %>% floor() %>% as.Date()`? And finally, why are these ghostly timestamps remaining in the numeric date?

```r
> dat$sample_date_time %>% 
    as.numeric() %>% 
    floor() %>% 
    unique() %>% 
    as.Date(origin = "1970-01-01")
[1] "2021-11-24"
```

Comment: The Date class is different than R data-time classes. If you use "%s" you get the time from the origin in seconds since you coerced that Date to POSIXt by including format codes that are not Date-specific.  . But if you use "%S" you get what you expected, the increment in second above the date and hours and minute. Except there would not be any incremental Hour Minute or Second because the assumed time of a Date classed variable is Midnight, so all of those would be 0. Those things you are calling "ghosts" are simply the value of a Date converted to POSIXct seconds since origin.

Comment: @IRTFM thanks for the explanation. You're right, I didn't include it in the original question, but when I did "%S" it also gave me all zeroes.

Comment: The OP clearly did his/her/their `unique` operation on data that had not yet been converted with as.Date. If they had already been converted there would not have been all those duplicate values.

Comment: The format parameter values are documented at `?strptime`

Comment: @IRTFM no operations were done to the data. Queried with DBI and then immediately `as.Date`. I just don't work with dates much usually.

Comment: I was saying that you had not yet done even the `as.Date` operation that you put in your question body.

Comment: Oh I see. No, I had done the `as.Date` bit, but it was not working, so I was getting to the point of ripping my hair out with frustration. I'm thinking I probably needed to set the format in `as.Date` function to prevent this?

Comment: Using `as.Date` should have been enough. It doesn't need a format string and `origin` is optional and defaults to the value you used so was superfluous. You haven't shown what the input to as.Date was. The SQLite docs say that numeric storage of dates can be in two forms:real and integer: `REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.`  So maybe your data was set up as "real Dates"? Not c/w what you show, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lubridate::floor_date` and then `distinct`:

```r
library(dplyr)

tibble(date = lubridate::floor_date(date_dates, unit = "day")) %>% 
  distinct(date)

# A tibble: 1 × 1
  date      
  <date>    
1 2021-11-24
```

or just `unique`:

```r
unique(lubridate::floor_date(date_dates, unit = "day"))
# [1] "2021-11-24"
```

Data

```r
date_nums <- c(18955.45, 18955.45, 18955.46, 18955.47, 18955.48, 18955.48)
date_dates <- as.Date(date_nums, origin = "1970-01-01")
```